# How to edit "This Shipping method is currently unavailable" message

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

In Magento 1.9 we need to edit message "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."

This message is displayed when the "Proceed to shipping method" button is clicked, while a shipping address was entered incorrectly (like zip doesn't match state) and user still selected that address as a shipping address.

So we want to change the message correspondingly (something like "We cannot find the address specified, please correct it.").

I have found "This shipping method is currently unavailable..." message in so many places and edited the message in all of them:

app/code/community/Shipperhq/Shipper/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php

I created "local" copies of those config.xml and the Error.php files in case they would override the core and community ones:

app/code/local/Shipperhq/Shipper/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php

I also found the message in Magento Admin: 
System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Method (so I changed the message in all the methods there)...

Flushed Magento Cache and Cache Storage...

But it still displays the same old message.

Please advice where and how to edit that persistent message "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us." Thank you much in advance!

Comment: modify at shipping methods at admin > system > configuration > sales > shipping methods > save

Comment: @Teja add this as an answer not a comment

Comment: @jscar, i just added answer. plz upvote if its worth. tnQ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that the message was also set on the SgipperHQ site and had to be edited from there. So many places with one same message...
Thank you Teja for trying to help and the advices you gave! they will be helpful for users around!

Comment: You are welcome, Please accept my answer

Comment: better use comment for feedback .

Answer (score 0):

You can change this message from admin panel.

```
admin > system > configuration > sales > shipping methods > save configuration
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I click "Save Config" (after changing the message in Admin Panel: System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Method)  I get two messages from magento: the 1st one is "ShipperHQ Error: Request Error. There was an error processing your request". The 2nd message though is green: "The configuration has been saved". The message on our website "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us." stays unchanged.

Comment: I cleared the ShipperHQ Error in there. But the message we need to have edited stays unchanged.

Comment: Change the scope of configuration and modify in website and default as well.

Comment: I think the only configuration we have set up (it was created by a vendor company) is a Default Configuration, as when I change the Current Configuration Scope dropdown to anything else it displays "404 Error page not found".

Comment: Well, while in admin > system > configuration > sales > shipping methods > I switched the Current Configuration Scope dropdown to "Main Website" value and Saved Configuration. I don't know if it was truly now saved for the Main Website Scope or did nothing, but nevertheless the old message is still there on our website...

Answer (score 0):

there is one possible reason for this error is the difference in origin and 
 allowed countries .

origin country in "sales>shipping setting" should be same as allowed country in 
"shipping method > method name > allowed country or specific country" .